# Potential energy: Electric field two spherical charges

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential-energy, classical-electrodynamics

I want to determine the potential energy of two equally charged spherical charges by using the equation: $V_{pot}= \int_V \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_0 E^2 dV$ and therefore I was wondering what I has to take as $E$? The sum of the electric fields of both charges? Notice, that I want to use this equation on purpose since it enables me to determine the potential energy in a particular volume.

Comment: Yes it's the total field.

Comment: Are the two spheres conductors? Isolators? (Things are getting complicated if spheres are conductors.)

Comment: They are conductors, what would be the equation then?

Comment: Well, it's quite complicated (excuse: I'm not in the mood to do that) because the distribution of charges in both spheres are no longer uniform.

Comment: Scratching quickly on a piece of paper, I think that there are no exact closed-form expression for $E$. (I can be wrong)